# Prevent Blazor PWA from reloading/refreshing after being minimized or inactive

Tags: c#, browser, blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly PWA (.NET 7) which takes around 15-30 seconds to initially start. Once the app has loaded, everything works fine but I am getting complaints that on Android (and I suppose on iOS) the app just sometimes refreshes/reloads. Especially if the user has minimized the app for a while, when the user restores the app, it somehow triggers a reload of the whole app and user needs to wait 15-30 seconds again.

Is there some way to prevent the app from reloading even after long inactivity? I want the app to stay active, or at least not refreshs upon restoring it. The app is hosted on IIS, I have removed the default service worker caching because it is not working, when enabled I get "ERR_FAILED" when I click Refresh, but that's a separate issue.

I have also deactivated the pull-to-refresh feature so the user does not accidently refresh the page.